# Azure FunctionsでBase64の文字列を読み込むとエラー413（request entity too large）が発生する。

Tags: c#, http, azure

Azure Functions(C#、Runtime .NET6、HttpTrigger)で
Http Request(POST/Type JSON)を受け取る際、ボディ部分のパラメータに
Base64の文字列(画像自体は85KBほどのものをエンコードしました)を入れると413エラー(request entity too large)が発生します。
Azure Functionsはスタンダードプランを使用しています。

#### 希望動作

POST RequestでBase64の文字列をAzure Functionsで受け取り、内容をlog.LogInformationで表示したい。

#### HttpRequest

```
{
 "image":"Base64形式の文字列～～(80KB)"
}
```

#### Azure Functions

```
    public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
        ILogger log)
    {
        //Build Count.
        log.LogInformation("BuiltNo.0011 AddInspectionRecord.cs");

        string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
        dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
        string lBaseString = data.image;

        log.LogInformation(lBaseString);    ###このログでBase64文字列を表示したい

        return new OkObjectResult("test");

    }
```

Comment: azure function request entity too large でググると色々ヒットしますが、そういうことはやってみたのでしょうか？

Comment: 色々と言われると幅広いですが、可能な限り検証は行いました。

Comment: 本件自力で解決できました。
以降の解決策は不要なので、コメントしなくてけっこうです。

Comment: 質問を消さないで元に戻して、あなたがどのように解決したかを書くようにしましょう。

Answer (score 1):

質問者さんは去ってしまって、どのように解決したかを書く気はなさそうですね。

なので、自分がこのスレッドを見て思ったことというレベルで回答にはなってませんが、以下に書いておきます。

azure function request entity too large でググるとヒットする記事には CORS の設定で問題を回避したというものがいくつか見られます。

[FIXED] Azure function failing : "statusCode": 413, "message": "request entity too large"
https://www.pythonfixing.com/2021/10/fixed-azure-function-failing-413-entity.html

何故 CORS が関係するのか不可解ではありますが、試してみてもよさそうだと思いました。

あと考えられるのは、実際に送信した JSON 文字列のサイズが too large なのかもということぐらいです。

古い話ですが ASP.NET Web サービスのメソッドに対してクライアントから JSON 文字列を送信する場合、サーバーへ送信できる JSON 文字列の長さはデフォルトで 102,400 文字に制限されています。

ASP.NET MVC アプリでは話が変わってきて、文字数制限は JavaScriptSerializerクラスの MaxJsonLength プロパティのデフォルト値 2,097,152 文字となります。

詳しくは以下の記事を見てください。

MVC は maxJsonLength を無視
http://surferonwww.info/BlogEngine/post/2013/08/07/asp-net-mvc-ignors-the-maxjsonlength-setting-in-web-config.aspx

Azure Functions は分かりませんが、同様な制限があるのかもしれません。